# segmentation fault with array storage

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a primitive version of brick breaker for an intro CS course. The method init Bricks instantiates a series of bricks which are of object type GRect. then the array brick_Array is meant to store those objects so that later I can tell if that ball has hit one of the objects. I'm pretty sure the default error is happening when I try to store the object in the array.

```
GRect brick_Array[COLS];

void initBricks(GWindow window, GRect brick_Array[])
{
    for (int column = 0; column < COLS; column++)
    {
        GRect brick = newGRect(column*40, 0, 37, 20);
        setColor(brick, "BLACK");
        setFilled(brick, true);
        add(window, brick);

        brick_Array[column] = brick;//segmentation fault
    }
}
```

Comment: Your this line is causing problem "brick_Array[column] = brick;"

Comment: This should be the way brick_Array[--column] = brick;

Comment: What do you pass in when you call `initBricks()`?

Comment: You have brick_Array[] as a function argument and brick_Array[COLS] as a global variable. Using global variables is generally considered bad style in C++ as it can lead to unintended behavior. I am not 100% sure, but if your error doesn't have something to do with the overlapping global variable/function argument, I would be very surprised. The reason I cannot give you a definite answer is because I have almost no experience using them.

Comment: I suspect you're passing the wrong array to the function, or an invalid pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to implement the copy constructor for GRect

```
GRect(GRect const &copy);
```

To test this you could try replacing:

```
GRect brick = newGRect(column*40, 0, 37, 20);
```

With:

```
brick_Array[column] = newGRect(column*40, 0, 37, 20);
```

You should probably also avoid sending variables to methods as a non-reference, as this causes them to by copied, for example `GWindow window` should be replaced with `GWindow &window`.

Comment: How would the default copy constructor (assuming the OP actually didn't implement one) possibly cause a segfault on assignment? It's much more likely that the code calling the function is passing a too-small array (or other invalid argument).